# react-native-fbsdk: How properly log out from facebook?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk npm package, which works properly. But when I call LoginManager.logOut() it does not do anything (even its callback function does not work). After first login it keeps all my data and after first loging and log out from the app , it keeps all my data and when I again press on FB icon to login with Facebook it only let me to login with the same account. There is no any other option. When I go to browser and log out from Facebook, the app works as needed (and allows me to log in with another account). But I need to entirely logout from exactly the app. Please help to solve the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution. The best workaround I got is to manually logout on safari.

Comment: same situation here :/

Comment: @David did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @httpete unfortunately not yet

Comment: @David I found a solution, that I use in dev mode. You can use `LoginManager.setLoginBehavior("web");` before login and it will ask for login/password again.